# Calculating Average trend with possible missing data

Tags: missing-data, mean

I am conducting a research on a group of subjects with population about 90. For each of them I have a time-serial datapoints such as:

```
  P1 =  [ [T1, 100],
          [T2, 23],
          [T3, 33],
           ... 
        ]  

   P2 =  [ [T1, 80],
           [T3, 77],
           [T4, 88]
           ... 
        ]  
   ...
```

Given that some datapoints are missing, for example, P2 doesn't have a datapoint for T2, how should I calculate the average for each time T? Should I simply use available points like

```
P1[T2] + P3[T2] + ... / 83
```

assuming that there are 83 datapoints at time T2

or should I "compensate" the missing data points like

```
P1[T2] + P2[somecompensited number] + P3[T2] + ... / 90
```

assuming 90 is the total population

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may want to do some sort of time series imputation. Imputation refers to the prediction of missing values so you can perform an analysis as if your data were complete. Some common (basic) choices for time series are last observation carried forward (if person 1 is missing T2, you would use substitute it with their value from T1) or the average of the individual's time series to fill in missing points.

Here's a link to an article, imputeTS: Time Series Missing ValueImputation in R, that might help you dig into this problem a little deeper: https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf

Comment: An average of values before and after is an alternative. A more sophisticated replacement value can be based on the arima structure e.g. 1,9,1,9,1,9,?,9 where a good estimate of the missing value would be"1" based upon the memory/arima structure